# ASP.NET MVC4 + jQuery Ajax, strange error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, localization

I have a weired error in one of my cshtml pages.

I have one layout page which renders a partial site, that has a language selector in it (dropdownlist, sets a cookie and does a postback).

And on the mentioned page I have two forms and two script tags, each containing an onclick eventhandler, so one handler for each form.

If I uncomment the "problematic" scripthandler my whole localization breaks! But there is no connection between the handler and the localization system.

This works perfectly

```
<script>

    $('#frmSubmitComment').submit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
           .....

    });

</script>
```

When I change the target to "form" like below, everything breaks, no breakpoint in my layout page is hit anymore and therefore the localization doesn't work:

```
<script>

    $('form').submit(function (e) {

        $.ajax({
     ...
</script>
```

When I change the target to #**frmSubmitComment**, my localization works again and also the breakpoints in my layout page are hitten again!

This must be a bug in VS2015 Enterprise, I don't get it ! It's like black magic :-)
I have also restarted VS, but it didn't help.
I cannot believe that changing the target id solves the problem, unbelievable.
The scripts are only called onclick.
When I visit the page I only try to change the language, that's all. Everything looks good...hmmm

What happens, when I change the target id to "form":
The languageController is not hit anymore.
On language change (dropdownlist selection) it calls the action of the form that is invoked by the script handler.

Here is the code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AjaxView";
}

<h2>AjaxView</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitComment", "AjaxController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmSubmitComment" }))
{

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <h3 class="AddAComment">Add a comment</h3>

    <div class="commentformwrapper">
        <div class="editor-text">
            <span class="editor-label">User Name:</span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-text">
            <input type="text" id="username" />
        </div>

        <div class="editor-text">
            <textarea id="comment" rows="6" cols="23"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="hidden" id="hiddendate" />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Form values as JSON object" />

    </div>
}

<script>

    //#frmSubmitComment: when I change the selector to #frmSubmitComment
    // everything is ok
    $('form').submit(function (e) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SubmitComment")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                PostId: 12,
                UserName: $('#username').val(),
                DateCreated: new Date(),
                CommentText: $('#comment').val()
            }),
            success: function (result) {
                alert("success " + result.UserName);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Failed");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

</script>



@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "AjaxController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ajaxForm", name = "ajaxForm" }))
{

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <h3 class="AddAComment">Add a comment</h3>

    <div class="commentformwrapper">
        <div class="editor-text">
            <span class="editor-label">User Name:</span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-text">
            <input type="text" name="username1" />
        </div>

        <div class="editor-text">
            <textarea name="comment1" rows="6" cols="23"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="hidden" name="hiddendate1" />
        </div>

        <button id="btnSub" name="Submit form values">Submit form values</button>

    </div>
}

<script>

    $("#btnSub").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SubmitForm","Ajax")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            //contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            data: $("#ajaxForm").serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                alert("success " + result.UserName);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Failed");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

</script>
```

This code is triggered by the dropdownlist:

```
function changeLanguage() {

    $.cookie('userlanguage', $("#ddlLanguages option:selected").val(), { domain: "localhost", expires: new Date(2200, 12), path: '/' });
    $("#formLang").submit();
}
```

this is the partial view of the language selector, which is rendered into the layoutpage:

```
@using WebApplication_MVC.Models;
@using System.Threading;

@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeCurrentLanguage", "Language", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", id = "formLang" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("ddlLanguages", new SelectList(LanguageModel.getLanguages(), "key", "value", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name), new {  @onchange = "changeLanguage()"})
    </div>
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/application");

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var lang = $.cookie('userlanguage');

        if (lang === undefined || $.trim(lang) == "") {
            $.cookie('userlanguage', $("#ddlLanguages option:selected").val(), { domain: "localhost", expires: new Date(2200, 12), path: '/' });

        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting breakpoints in the browser and see if the request is actually being sent.

Comment: Can you also show the code for dropdown onclick handler? Also try `$("form:first")` to confirm if its a target selector problem\.

Comment: @Abishek Siddhu, When the page is rendered, the first thing I do is to change the language in the dropdownlist, this triggers the clientside changelanguage function, which calls     '$("#formLang").submit();
Right after that, the  $('form').submit handler is triggered! Why, I don't know?! Which then, of course calls the SubmitComment action in the AjaxController. The question here is, why the "$('form').submit" is triggered, instead of triggering a full postback with $("#formLang").submit(); ...

Comment: @Dandy, it's not a selector problem, the first thing I do on that page, is changing the language, that's all.

Comment: I think I will give a bounty for that, if this is an error in my code causing the problem, it's rather a bug in the IDE or MVC framework.... usually the problem sits behind the computer :-)